# How do i add delegate to an object in tableViewCell?

Tags: ios, swift

In View Controller there is viewDidLoad where I could add delegate and so on, 
for example

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // for example
        tableView.delegate = self
}
```

In tableViewCell , the only default method that has been created is

```
@IBOutlet var mapView: GMSMapView!
 // This method
 override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
    }
```

Because I really need to add delegate to the map.

Answer (score 1):

if your use UIBTableView and you need to set delegate to some of objects in UITableViewCell than best way to do it in

```
-(UITableViewCell)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;
```

but you shouldn't forget to clear delegate, best way to do it in your subclass of UITableViewCell

```
-(void)prepareForReuse;
```

**In Swift**

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView,
cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell

override func prepareForReuse()
```

Comment: can you write it in swift?